# prevent access to mysql database from unauthorized software

Tags: java, mysql, authentication, remote-access

i am writing an application in java and i want to enable it to access a mysql remote server.
my problem is that if the application have the user name and password someone can take them and use my db with a different software.
is there a way of preventing it ?

**UPDATE**

i found [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database) workaround for connecting to a remote MySQL database from an android device.
you put a service in the middle. like a php page that code the data in JSON format which the android app gets via http.
here is the example i found :
[Connecting to MySQL database](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database)

Comment: Do you mean that the application holds hard-coded DB credentials?

Comment: yes, if i use hibernate then those are defined in the hibernate.cfg.xml file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having the username and password is designed specifically to grant access to the database. That's the whole point.

You could go to some extra lengths like restricting database connectivity to specific hosts, so at least your paying customers get access to the database and no else can access it, but your customers might choose to use different software to access the database. There's no way around it except licensing terms.

What you *could* do is run an intermediary program on your own hardware that connects to the database and restrict access to the database to software that is under your direct administrative control. Your program would validate all requests from software under control of your customers and allow the queries that you want to allow and refuse (and log) the queries you do not have to allow. (You do not need to send raw SQL data back and forth -- you can do any amount of processing on the data and queries.)

Answer (score 0):

You can setup JDBC Data Source on your application server. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2432/gkyan.html) you can see example for Oracle Glassfish.

So, your credential won't be used in your code/resources.

Comment: As far as I know, jdbc connection exposed via JNDI would not be available remotely (outside of current JVM).

Comment: You're right. But i don't see such problem(use connection from another JVM) from author's post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that you have an application trying to access a MySQL remotely (not in the same box), then i think you need not worry, as the connection that will be established by your application codes will not expose the username and password when it is trying to authenticate and authorize itself to the MySQL server.

Comment: it wont but information is stored inside the software so if someone want to he can extract that info, especially since java is an Interpreted language

Comment: Many a times this is an issue, there are tonnes of secret information inside an application's configuration XML. I too wanna hear what are the options. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the access to the MySQL-server so that only certain IP-addresses or IP-ranges have access to it.

As a side note, make sure that the user you use in your application only has the needed permissions to the database. For example, the user might not need to be able to create or delete tables. You can even specify permissions for the user on table and column level.

Comment: that wont help cause i dont know from which ip's the server will be accessed from.